# DigitalOcean & Letsencrypt - how to install SSL for HTTPS

Tags: ssl, https, digital-ocean

I have a droplet with DigitalOcean and I am trying to set an ssl certificate via letsencrypt to add https to my domain.

When I run the following command as sudo in the droplet CLI:

```
sudo letsencrypt --apache -d example.com -d www.example.com
```

I get the following error:

```
(98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
(98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
AH00015: Unable to open logs
```

What does this error mean, what do I need to do?

Answer (score 1):

You likely already have a webserver running on port 80.

What you could do is temporarily stop that webserver, which mostly likely works on linux using either `sudo service apache2 stop` or `sudo service nginx stop`.

Then you should be able to run the challenge.

Afterwards you need to start it again.